# T4 Text Generation Partial Classes

Tags: c#, .net, t4

I'm testing out the capabilities of T4 Text Templating for run-time text generation.

At [MSDN - Run-Time Text Generation with T4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844259.aspx) it states:

> Usually a template must import some data from other parts of the
>   application. To make this easy, the code built by the template is a
>   partial class. You can create another part of the same class in
>   another file in your project. That file can include a constructor with
>   parameters, properties and functions that can accessed both by the
>   code that is embedded in the template, and by the rest of the
>   application.

I tried this (VS2017 - .NET 4.6.1) and get the following errors when I compile -

> 'CSharpFunction' does not contain a definition for 'TransformText'
>
> A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods
>
> Compiling transformation: The name 'FunctionName' does not exist in the current context
>
> The name 'ErrorGeneratingOutput' does not exist in the current context.

**CSharpFunction.cs**

```
partial class CSharpFunction
{
    private string FunctionName;

    public CSharpFunction(string functionName)
    {
        FunctionName = functionName;
    }
}
```

**CSharpFunction.tt**

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
public void <#=FunctionName#>()
{
    Console.WriteLine("<#=FunctionName#>");
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = new CSharpFunction("Test");
        string output = obj.TransformText();
        Console.WriteLine(output);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes it will work for **run time templates**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure your runtime text template file's property **Custom Tools** is set to **TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor**.

This is done automatically by creating a **runtime text template** which is a different file type from a **text template** when creating it in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Naxin, well did you run it? If you see the header of tt file, it is different and that's the different between regular tt file and rtg tt file. Just paste it and run, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: So the issue I still have, is if I Save the file I receive the error as per my post. If I don't save the file, the object doesn't have the TransformText function.

Comment: @Naxin, Why don't you create a blank project and try with only files I mentioned here. I'm using VS 2017, C# 7, .Net 4.6.1 and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Yes I've done that, I get the same issue - VS2017 .NET 4.6.1

Comment: I will update my question with your code and the additional errors.

Comment: @Naxin, download code from https://github.com/dipen08it419/RunTimeTextGenerationDemo, see if it works.

Comment: By referencing your project, I was able to determine the issue was that the "CustomTool" property of the TT file was set to "TextTemplatingFileGenerator" instead of "TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor". I realised that this is because when creating the TT file, I chose "Text Template" instead of "Runtime Text Template" which affects this property. If you could edit your answer to make this information clearer I'd be happy to mark your answer as correct! I really appreciate working through this with me.

Comment: @Naxin Sure, I'll. Happy to help!

Comment: strange, i specifically added new "Runtime Text Template" and it has the property set to TextTemplatingFileGenerator. With visual studio 2019, i guess this is a bug? I did install some t4 template editor extension maybe this has broken something...